# Coarsest and Finest Topology

Tags: general-topology

Any collection of topologies has a greatest lower bound among all topologies:
$$\inf_{i\in I}\mathcal{T}_i=\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal{T}_i\text{ for }I\neq\{\}\\
\inf_{i\in I}\mathcal{T}_i=\mathcal{P}(X)\text{ for }I=\{\}$$
Especially that means:
$$\inf_{i\in I}\mathcal{T}_i\text{ always exists}$$
Since $\inf A=\sup A_-$ and $\sup A=\inf A_+$ (see [Suprema vs Infima](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/844062/79762)) also:
$$\sup_{i\in I}\mathcal{T}_i\text{ always exists}$$
Thus any collection admits a coarsest topology:
$$\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{A}:=\inf_{\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{T}}\mathcal{T}:\quad \mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{A}$$
That is precisely saying the infimum was a minimum:
$$\inf_{\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{T}}\mathcal{T}=\min_{\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{T}}\mathcal{T}$$

**Assuming only collections containing the chaotic topology: $\{\varnothing,X\}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$**

**Does the same hold true mutatis mutandum for coarsest topology being replaced by finest topology?**

Comment: No. For example if the family does not contain the empty set.

Comment: Ok and what if the family contains at least the empty set and the space itself: $\varnothing,X\in\mathcal{A}$

Comment: Then it depends on whether the smallest generated topology is a subset of the given family or not. Maybe you could add the new assumption to the question and then someone more knowledgable than myself will write an answer.

Comment: (Correction of earlier comment): Suppose $X$ is the set in which we are working, and suppose $\mathcal{A} = \{\emptyset,A,B,X\}$ where $A,B$ are disjoint. Then $\{\emptyset,A,X\}$ and $\{\emptyset,B,X\}$ are distinct finest topologies in $\mathcal{A}$. This shows that there cannot be a **unique** finest topology, if that was part of your question.

Comment: Cool so that's it

Comment: Ok I added assumptions to the question. Does your comment still work for it? Moreover, can you put your comment as answer please. Besides, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is due to Lee Mosher. Thank you alot!*

Suppose neither $A\nsubseteq B$ nor $B\nsubseteq A$ and consider the collections $\mathcal{A}=\{\varnothing,A,B,X\}$. Then:
$$\sup_{\mathcal{A}\supseteq\mathcal{T}}\mathcal{T}=\{\varnothing,A,B,A\cap B,X\}\nsubseteq\mathcal{A}$$

This also illuminates what usually happens:
$$\{\varnothing,X\}\subseteq\mathcal{A},\{\varnothing,A,X\}\subseteq\mathcal{A},\{\varnothing,B,X\}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$$
**So the supremum was no maximum!**

Similarly we have for the empty collection $\mathcal{A}=\{\}$:
$$\sup_{\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{T}}=\{\varnothing,X\}\nsubseteq\mathcal{A}$$